# Fetching JSON and rendering it with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My fetch gives me the following JSON:

"{"name":"John","age":26,"city":"London"}"

However when i try to render it on my page like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            files: result.files
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
  
  render() {  
    const { error, isLoaded, files } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (     
        <ul>
          {files.map(file => (
            <li key={file.id}>
              {file.name} {file.age} {file.city}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>       
      );
    }
    
  }

}
export default Tab;
```

I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you expect result.files to be an array when the JSON has nothing named files and no arrays at all?

Comment: @Quentin it should be an array. The function looks like this in PHP:
`Code:
$myArray = array("name" => "John", "age" => 26, "city" => "London");
    $myJSON = json_encode($myArray);

    return $myJSON;
`

Comment: @Quentin it doesnt need to be an array though, i just need to figure out how to display "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":26,\"city\":\"London\"}" with my render.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see everything your code is doing. I suspect you just have bad initial state, or it's that `result.files` isn't what you expect it to be. It's unclear where the example fetch result fits in with your code and error.

Comment: @7BitAscii an "associative array" in php seems to output astring equivalent to an object in JSON. Maybe don't use `=>`?

Comment: Well, if `"{"name":"John","age":26,"city":"London"}"` is the response result, there is no `files` property, so `result.files`, and thus `this.state.files`, is undefined.

Comment: @DrewReese ok that makes sense, the previous output of my fetch was: `{
  "files": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Coderegels", "type": " txt" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Urenplanning","type":" xls" }
  ] 
}`

So i tried to just edit what i had to make that show. But since the current output is `"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":26,\"city\":\"London\"}"`
How do i take items from that and render them? Like name for example.

Comment: @DrewReese this doesnt seem to work as it appears name from `"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":26,\"city\":\"London\"}"` isnt actually referring to John. It's actually returning Null. So im getting the error: Error: Tab(...): Nothing was returned from render. Any idea why its not grabbing "John" when im using `this.setState({isLoaded: true, name: result.name});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the API response is `{"name":"John","age":26,"city":"London"}` then I suggest the following:

1. Save the entire response result into state. Use a `catch` block to catch any errors and set any error state, and use a `finally` block to set the loading state (more ***DRY***).

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     fetch("http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=")
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then((result) => {
         this.setState({ ...result });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         this.setState({ error });
       })
       .finally(() => {
         this.setState({ isLoaded: true })
       });
   }
   ```
2. Render from state, no array, just the state fields.

   ```
   render() {  
     const { error, isLoaded, name, age, city } = this.state;

     if (error) {
       return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
     } else if (!isLoaded) {
       return <div>Loading...</div>;
     } else {
       return (     
         <ul>
           <li>
             {name} {age} {city}
           </li>
         </ul>       
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: This fixed errors from showing, but its not rendering the name, age and city on the page for some reason. Just a big black dot.

Comment: Fixed it. For some reason the json_encode() of my array makes it so its no longer an array. Hence it would not connect the name to John, the Age to 26, etc.